# FOSUserBundle getRoles admin

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I added to my User class a field like that
`/**
  * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
*/
protected $isOp;`
I need to override
**UserInterface->getRoles()** method and return ALL of the Roles I have.
`Role` is an `Entity`, which implements `RoleInterface` provided by FOS.
And inside any of my templates when I call `is_granted('ROLE_DOUGH')` I need to immediately get TRUE if User's group is marked as `Operator` (isOp field).

Comment: Great. Now, what is your problem ?

Comment: Well, getRoles method is located in my Entity, and I need to return array of entities stored in db.

Comment: How to implement this w/o perversion of M-V-C approach?